# What does glassware accuracy and precision (tolerance) mean statistically?

Tags: everyday-life, statistics

According to Daniel C. Harris (Table 2-5, 9th edition), a 25 mL volumetric pipet has an accuracy of +- 0.06 mL and a precision of +- 0.02 mL.

I'm trying to understand what these values mean from a statistical definition:

1.) a.) **Is the "accuracy" value of 0.06 mL indicate a tolerance interval? If so, what is the confidence level and tolerance level(is it assumed 99% for both?) for that tolerance interval?** In other words, if 100 experiments of 100 trials using that pipet were done: 99 of those 100 experiments would have at least 99 trials with results between 24.94 and 25.06?

1.) b.) **Or is accuracy simply the TOLERANCE (permissible range of variation  from its nominal value) of the pipet?** If so, how is tolerance for glassware determined? Is it arbitrary or is it based on the error inherent in the production process (like the mold used to hold the smelted glass)?

2.) **Is the "precision" value of 0.02 mL indicate the population standard deviation?** In other words, is it saying that 65% (one standard deviation for a normally distributed population) of all measurements would fall within 24.98 and 25.02?

3.) **Does the precision of the glassware assume perfect sampling technique?** If so, can the precision uncertainty be directly compounded with the sampling technique uncertainty?

For example:

If the pipet was used 10 times to reveal a sample standard deviation of +- 0.03 mL. Does it mean that 0.02 of that interval is due to the glassware and 0.01 of that interval is a consequence of sampling technique variance?